# How can you edit powershell_ise.exe.config?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make changes to my PowerShell ISE config file at ...

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe.config`

Originally its owner was set to the TrustedInstaller, so changed it to me. Also gave my account Full Control on the file

Editing the file in Notepad++ running as Admin

When I try to save any change, I get "Save failed", "Please check this file is opened in another program".

Did a search for 'powershell_ise.exe.config' using Process Explorer but nothing found

So what has got the file opened?

And more important ... **how do I make changes to the config file?**

Comment: Why would you want to edit it in the first place? My guess would be that it's a system protected file and some system process is accessing it. On my Windows 7 system that file doesn't exist. See also: [cannot edit powershell_ise.exe.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300255/cannot-edit-powershell-ise-exe-config-file) which suggests renaming the file.

Comment: @Seth In this case I want to add the DefaultProxy settings so ISE can go through the proxy to get ISE Steroids module

Comment: Tried the rename trick ... no joy. Make the change, rename back and the change disappeared. Searching disk and I can see another two copies of powershell_ise.exe.config in the C:\Windows\winsxs\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your own windows is blocking changes due the fact of being using powershell or even because being a protected file. When that happends to me I usually reboot the system and boot into a [Windows PE enviroment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment#Windows_Recovery_Environment). Being there just open a Command-line instance and notepad.exe the config file.

By the way, be careful of editing such files, some are essential for Windows functions.

Comment: Sorry being stupid ... how do I boot into Windows PE?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-usb-bootable-win-pe-windows-10-jasmin-kahriman

Comment: or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdpnzQiYfV4